# How do I sort post listing by child post count?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, sort, pre-get-posts, children

I have two custom post types called questions and answers. The questions list includes a custom column which displays a count of the answers for each question. I need to be able to sort the listing based on the number of answers.

This query works via the MySQL shell and provides the proper output:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.post_title, COUNT(b.ID) AS child_count
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_posts b
ON a.ID = b.post_parent AND b.post_status = 'publish' AND b.post_type = 'answer'
WHERE a.post_type = 'question' AND a.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY a.ID
ORDER BY child_count DESC
```

My code so far:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'column_orderby' );
function column_orderby( $query ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() )
    return;
  $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' );
  if ( 'qa-answers' == $orderby ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query->set( 'posts_join', "LEFT JOIN wp_posts b ON a.ID = b.post_parent AND b.post_status = 'publish'" );
    $query->set( 'posts_groupby', "{$wpdb->posts}.ID" );
  }
}
```

How can the `COUNT(b.ID) AS child_count` clause be added to the query so that I can reference this in a `$query->set('orderby', 'child_count');` statement?

Comment: Where does this need to work? What query are you trying to alter?

Comment: The code is within a plugin and the question listing is an admin page (wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=question&orderby=qa-answers&order=asc).

Answer (score 0):

Based on my subsequent review of wp-includes/query.php, what I was attempting is simply not possible. This is because the query vars may only be modified to predefined set of values. As best I can determine, you cannot arbitrarily modify queries.